# CSS Submeu appears on hover, but disappears when when I try to go to submenu

Tags: html, css

Hi all I have this menu like so:

As you can see I have a submenu inside a submenu, now when I hover over "In Person" my submenu appears, but disappears when I try to go to the submenu, how do I fix that? Here is my CSS:

```css
li.menu-in-person ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: none !important;
}

li.menu-in-person:hover ul.dropdown-menu,
li.menu-in-person ul.dropdown-menu:hover {
  display: block !important;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav li:last-child .dropdown-menu {
  right: -174px;
  left: auto;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown menu-services"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="menu-online"><a href="http://example.com/online-health-coaching/">Online</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown menu-in-person"><a href="#">In Person</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="menu-classes"><a href="http://example.com/classes/">Classes</a></li>
        <li class="menu-corporate-wellness"><a href="http://example.com/corporate-wellness/">Corporate Wellness</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Code seems to work for me when put into a Code Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBJrya

Comment: Not working on my site at all, the sucker disappears on me

Comment: DM me and I will show you the link.

Comment: i have created a code snippet. can you please tell me whats is wrong

Comment: Okay, When I hover over Services, a dropdown appears, all is good, then I goto hover over In Person and my second dropdown appears, all is good, when I try to put my mouse over anything in the second dropdown menu the second dropdown menu disappears right away and I am not able to get to it.

Comment: @user979331 can you please post fiddle here?

Comment: Here is the site in question: http://annapiotrowski.com

Comment: works on my system.

Comment: I think the problem is the padding on the right side of the initial drop down menu. If you move fast enough the sub menu stays, but moving slowly causes it to hide. Try removing the padding on the right hand side and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be reproduce on your live site http://annapiotrowski.com/, when you move the mouse slowly from **in person** to there sub menu. The sub menu disappeared because of `padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px` CSS on `dropdown-menu`. Follow my CSS updates i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Change `padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px !important` to `padding: 0 !important` on **line number 1205** in your `style.css`

```
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7) !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Change `right: -174px;` to `right: -160px;` on **line number 35** in your `style.css`

```
.navbar .navbar-nav li:last-child .dropdown-menu {
  right: -160px;
  left: auto;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Change `padding:8px 20px;` to `padding:12px 20px;` on **line number 223** in your `responsive.css`

```
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a {
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    color:#c8c8c8;
}
```

Comment: Just tried this, it did not work, your code is currently applied to the site.

Comment: It's working fine on live site and please change `right: -169px;` to `right: -160px;` on **line number 35** in your `style.css` and hit `clrl + f5`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```css
ul.sub-menu, ul.sub-dropdown {
  display: none !important;
}

li.menu-services:hover ul.sub-menu,
li.menu-services:focus ul.sub-menu {
  display: block !important;
}


li.menu-in-person:hover ul.sub-dropdown,
li.menu-in-person:focus ul.sub-dropdown {
  display: block !important;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav li:last-child .dropdown-menu {
  right: -174px;
  left: auto;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
    <li class="dropdown menu-services"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-online"><a href="http://example.com/online-health-coaching/">Online</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown menu-in-person"><a href="#">In Person</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-dropdown">
            <li class="menu-classes"><a href="http://example.com/classes/">Classes</a></li>
            <li class="menu-corporate-wellness"><a href="http://example.com/corporate-wellness/">Corporate Wellness</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Almost, However I don't wont the submenu (Classes and Corporate Wellness) to appear until I hover over In Person

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you mean, but this is a snippet from my website. Is this what you were looking for?

```html
<style type="text/css">
   body {
    background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/calvinhaworth/image/upload/v1552847132/darkgreybackgroundwebsite.jpg);
    height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
   }
    div.cntr {
     text-align: center;
    }
    .logo:hover {
      -webkit-filter: blur(2px); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: blur(2px);
    }
    div.cntr {
     text-align: center;
    }
    .linkright {
     font-family: "IBM Plex Serif", serif;
     background-color: black;
     color: Aqua;
     border: ridge 10px black;
     margin-top: 25;
    }
    .linkright:hover {
     font-family: "IBM Plex Serif", serif;
     color: black;
     background-color: white;
     border: 10px ridge purple;
     margin-top: 25;
    }
    .linkinside {
     color: blue;
    }
    .linkinside:hover {
     color: black;
    }
    .wrapper {
     font-family: "IBM Plex Serif", serif;
     border: 5px ridge black;
     border-radius: 25px;
     padding: 20px;
     margin-left: 100px;
     margin-right: 100px;
     background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
    }

 .dropbtn {
 font-family: "IBM Plex Serif", serif;
   margin-top: 15px;
   background-color: black;
   color: Aqua;
   font-size:16px;
   border: 10px ridge black;
   border-radius: 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .dropdown {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 
 .dropdown-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: black;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   z-index: 1;
   border: 10px ridge black;
   border-radius: 10px;
 }
 
 .dropdown-content a {
   color: aqua;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
 }
 
 .dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white 
 }
 
 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;
 }
 
 .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
   background-color: white;
 }
 .about {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 }
 .stick {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
 }
  </style>
  
  <div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="dropbtn"><u>Extra Links (Mouse Over)</u></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a rel="noopener noreferrer"  target="_blank" href="http://calvinhaworth.x10host.com/english19thdesktop/"><u>English I</u></a>
       <a rel="noopener noreferrer"  target="_blank" href="http://calvinhaworth.x10host.com/inmath19thdesktop/"><u>Integrated Math I</u></a>
       <a rel="noopener noreferrer"  target="_blank" href="http://calvinhaworth.x10host.com/geo9thgradedesktop/"><u>Geography</u></a>
       <a rel="noopener noreferrer"  target="_blank" href="http://calvinhaworth.x10host.com/teamlife9thdesktop/"><u>Team/Life Activities</u></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

May i ask why did u put  the display to none?

**{ display: none !important; }**

I was just assuming btw. The code should be like this i suppose

**{ display: block !important; }**

Comment: I use display none because I dont want to display the submenu inside the submenu until I hover over the link.